# TypeError: Object of type NAType is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, python-3.8

Thank you in advance for your help.

My python code reads json input file and loads the data into a data frame, masks or changes on the data frame column specified by configuration and in the last stage, creates json output file.

```
read json into data frame --> mask/change the df column ---> generate json
```

Input json:

```
[
    {
        "BinLogFilename": "mysql.log",
        "Type": "UPDATE",
        "Table": "users",
        "ServerId": 1,
        "BinLogPosition": 2111
    },        {
    {   "BinLogFilename": "mysql.log",
        "Type": "UPDATE",
        "Table": "users",
        "ServerId": null,
        "BinLogPosition": 2111
    },
  ...
]
```

when I load the above json into data frame, the data frame column "ServerId" has float values because it has null in few blocks of json input.

The main central logic converts/fakes "ServerId" into another number, however the output contains float numbers.

Output json:

```
[
      {
            "BinLogFilename": "mysql.log",
            "Type": "UPDATE",
            "Table": "users",
            "ServerId": 5627.0,
            "BinLogPosition": 2111
        }, 
        {
            "BinLogFilename": "mysql.log",
            "Type": "UPDATE",
            "Table": "users",
            "ServerId": null,
            "BinLogPosition": 2111
        },
     ....
]
```

masking logic

```
df['ServerId'] = [fake.pyint() if not(pd.isna(df['ServerId'][index])) else np.nan for index in range(len(df['ServerId']))]
```

The challenge is, the output "ServerId" should contain only integers but unfortunately it contains floats.

```
df['ServerId']
0     9590.0
1        NaN
2     1779.0
3     1303.0
4        NaN
```

I found a answer to this problem, to use 'Int64'

```
df['ServerId'] = df['ServerId'].astype('Int64')
0     8920
1     <NA>
2     9148
3     2434
4     <NA>
```

However using 'Int64', it converts NaN to NA and while writing back to json, i get an error as,

> TypeError: Object of type NAType is not JSON serializable

```
with gzip.open(outputFile, 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.write(json.dumps(json_objects_list).encode('utf-8'))
```

Is it possible to keep NaN after converting to 'Int64' data type? If this is not possible, how can i fix the error?

Comment: can you replace `NaN` with 0

Comment: Few times the input may also contain 0

Comment: `fillna` can be used to fill any value , use a high value - `MAX_INT`

Comment: Dataframes have options for ignoring/converting Null data: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/missing_data.html Depending on how you load the json into the dataframe you could also use arguments like `keep_default_na=False`. For example: `pd.read_csv('foo.csv', keep_default_na=False)`

Comment: Is it something possible without using MAX_INT or any other negative number? I am worried MAX_INT could be as well in the input.

Comment: If the json input is null, the output should also be null for the 'ServerId'

Comment: did you ever find an answer to this @Hari ?

Comment: @Thomas, So far no results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, Pandas NA and NaT are not JSON serialisable by the built-in Python *json* library.

But the Pandas DataFrame *to_json()* method will handle those values for you and convert them to JSON null.

```
from pandas import DataFrame, Series, NA, NaT

df = DataFrame({"ServerId" : Series([8920, NA, 9148, 2434, NA], dtype="Int64") })
s = df.to_json()

# -> {"ServerId":{"0":8920,"1":null,"2":9148,"3":2434,"4":null}}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add your custom json encoder like this:

```
from decimal import Decimal
from pandas._libs.missing import NAType
    
class MyEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, Decimal):
            return str(obj)
        if isinstance(obj, NAType):
            return ""
        # ️ otherwise use the default behavior
        return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)
```

And then you can pass it to json.dumps(), for example:

```
print(json.dumps(list(df.T.to_dict().values()), indent=4, cls=MyEncoder))
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is related to the fact that some of the values in your pandas DataFrame are `pd.NaT` and will then cause troubles when calling `json.dumps()`.

---

One possible solution is to replace all missing values (including `None`, `pd.NaT`, `numpy.nan` and really any other missing value-realted type) first with `np.nan` and then replace the latter with `None`:

```
import numpy as np

df = df.fillna(np.nan).replace([np.nan], [None])
```